# Mongokit add objects to collection

Tags: python, mongodb, crud, pymongo, mongokit

How do you insert objects to a collection in using MongoKit in Python?

I understand you can specify the '**collection**' field in a model and that you can create models in the db like

```
user = db.Users()
```

Then save the object like

```
user.save()
```

However I can't seem to find any mention of an insert function. If I create a User object and now want to insert it into a specific collection, say "online_users", what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completely guessing it appears I can successfully just call

```
db.online_users.insert(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new Document called `OnlineUser` with the `__collection__` field set to `online_users`, and then you have to related `User` and `OnlineUsers` with either `ObjectID` or `DBRef`. MongoKit [supports both](http://namlook.github.io/mongokit/structure.html) through -

- pymongo.objectid.ObjectId
- bson.dbref.DBRef

You can also use `list` of any other field type as a field.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `user` object is a dict like

```
user = {
    "one": "balabala",
    "two": "lalala",
    "more": "I am happy always!"
}
```

And here is my solution, not nice but work :)

```
online_users = db.Online_users()  # connecting your collection

for item in user:
    if item == "item you don't want":
        continue  # skip any item you don't want
    online_users[item] = user[item]

online_users.save()
db.close()  # close the db connection
```